# MS access insert query not working with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I Have the below code as part of Excel upload functionality. The insert query that i have used doesn't work because of the WHERE clause. Can someone please help me with suggestions.

```
Private Sub lblupload_Click()
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim strsql As String
Dim strsql1 As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset

If FSO.FileExists(Me.txtFileName) Then

    Excelimport.importexcel Me.txtFileName, "tblimportdatatmp"
    strsql = "Select distinct[Trans Day] from tblimportdatatmp;"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strsql)

    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
       
       rs.MoveFirst
       While Not rs.EOF
          strsql1 = "Select * from tblimportdata where [Trans Day] IN (select [Trans Day] from  tblimportdatatmp);"
          Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strsql1)
          If rs1.RecordCount = 0 Then
              CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblimportdata SELECT * from tblimportdatatmp where  [Trans Day]  = " & rs.Fields("[Trans Day]") & " ;"
          Else
              MsgBox " records already exists! "
          End If
          rs.MoveNext
       Wend
       
    End If

Else
    MsgBox "File not found !"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What field type is [Trans Day]? To get accurate RecordCourt, probably need to first use `rs1.MoveLast`.

Comment: [Trans Date] at table level it is Date/Time

Comment: If it is a date/time type field, need # delimiters. `= #" & rs.Fields("[Trans Day]") & "#;"`

Comment: Tried with delimiters but it is throwing syntax erro:
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblimportdata SELECT * from tblimportdatatmp where  where DateValue( [Trans Day] ) = #" & rs.Fields("[Trans Day]") & "# ;"

Comment: Syntax works for me. I presume double `where` is just a typo in comment. Since not specifying fields in INSERT or SELECT clauses, fields must be same order and types in both tables. If there is an autonumber field in destination table, it should be last in table design and presume there is no autonumber field in the tmp table.

Comment: Okay the query is getting executed now but with unsuccessful results. Though they execute I do not see them inserting values into table. Any alternative suggestions will be helpful

Comment: Include the `dbFailOnError` with `CurrentDb.Execute` to see whether it reveals additional information about failed inserts.